# Cappelletti Overcalled

Tags: bridge, bidding

If the intervener is overcalled by a responders to the 1NT what are the options for the advancer in addition to the standard responses. Is he now allowed to pass meaning partner I cannot help.

Answer (score 4):

Assumption:

Your partnership agreement for Capelletti is [as outlined on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappelletti_convention)

Absolutely Advancer can pass; the work of interference has been performed. Doing so is a *de facto* statement by Advancer that he is uninterested in continuing the auction, either because of a paucity of points or lack of fit or both.

The general philosophy is the same for a preemptive opening at the 2-level or higher: the initial bid should be so descriptive that there is no temptation by the initial caller (Intervenor in this case) to continue the auction unilaterally.

Comment: *Absolutely Advancer can pass* --- surely they'd better not pass the artificial 2C or 2D with 0 HCP and a 4333, though.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Whenever the hand is a potential misfit it is ***imperative*** to give the opponents useful information as slowly as possible. If Advancer has a one-suiter himself in either Clubs or Diamonds, and especially if weak, it is quite appropriate to pass (with intent of converting an opposing Double to 2D in the latter case). Asking Overcaller to identify his suit in this case immediately tells opponents how to play or defend the hand - before the auction is even over. Just. Don't. Do. That.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: If Advancer has a 4333 hand that ***guarantees***  a double fit of at least 8-7 - ***and potentially 8-8 or 9-8*** - or a single fit of 9+. Even with 0 points Advancer is positively interested in continuing the interference in this case, as Overcaller's shortness is valuable in a Dummy Reversal.

Comment: Strong agreement. Partner's Cappelletti interference indicates that there is a mine field of at least some distributional surprise in store for the opponents (should they own the hand and try a game contract). It is imperative not to hand them a map pin-pointing the locations of the mines (as well as the opportunity to penalize your side). Of course, with the sign of a fit, you pre-empt all you are worth (on weak hands).